# On boundary-value problems for differential forms on a manifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry, elliptic-pde, differential-forms

Let $M$ be a simply-connected $d$-dimensional Riemannian manifold with boundary (for simplicity assume a ball). Consider the boundary value problem for $\omega\in\Omega^k(M)$,
$$
d\omega = \alpha
\qquad
\delta\omega = \beta
\qquad
t(\omega) = 0,
$$
where $d\alpha=0$, $\delta\beta=0$ and $t$ is the tangential boundary operator. Since the topology of $M$ is trivial, this problem has a unique solution.

My question is under what conditions on $\alpha$ and $\beta$ the solution satisfies $n(\omega)=0$, where $n$ is the normal boundary operator. I suspect the answer to be $t(\alpha)=0$ and $n(\beta)=0$ but I failed to prove it so far.